# Unable to resolve 'requests'. IntelliSense may be missing for this module. Visual Studio/Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip, python-requests, intellisense

Using Visual Studio with Python. I'm getting this warning when importing requests.

### [image]

```
Unable to resolve 'requests'. IntelliSense may be missing for this module.
```

In the Python Environments tab, you can see that I have requests installed down in my packages.

### [image]

I'd like to have IntelliSense while working with 'requests'. Is there something I may have overlooked?

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if the issue still exists :)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT it started working for me all the sudden, not sure what I did/didn't do. Thanks for the help regardless! I'll keep the question up in case your solution helps someone else with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe your situation is something like the issue2 in my answer. Sometimes when you install a **new** package, the intellisense won't work immediately in **current** project. But if you `reload the project, or create a new project, or restart the VS`, the intellisense will always work for this package cause after a reload(VS restart will reload the project automatically). And this issue will only occur one time when you install the package for the first time, if you install a new package which you haven't installed, you would find this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Maybe it's something similar to [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/2596). Deleting the *init*.py in top-level of your project can help resolve this issue.

2.If the above not helps, please try **reloading the project**.

After my test, sometimes in a python application, after the first time we install a python package, the **intellisense** for the new package in **current project** won't work until we **reload the project file** to recognize the new package.

For this situation, the easy workaround is: `Right-click the project` in `Solution Explorer`=>choose `unload the project`=>Right-click it again and `choose reload the project`. Then the intellisense for the new package would work well.

Hope it helps and sorry for the delay!